# Video player in Javascript stuck at hidden/display circle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, dom-events

In this small project I am coding video player in browser. Currently I am working on play/pause button when you click on the video. The animation in CSS is working, but when I click the button on the screen it disappears and that's right. When I click again I should see the pause button, but instead I just have the play button again. Finally it should behave like the button on YouTube on the screen.  In JavaScript it's grabbed under the variable`const butto = player.querySelector('.buttom')`

```js
const player = document.querySelector('.player');
const video = player.querySelector('.viewer');
const progress = player.querySelector('.progress');
const progressBar = player.querySelector('.progress__filled');
const toggle = player.querySelector('.toggle');
const skipButtons = player.querySelectorAll('[data-skip]');
const ranges = player.querySelectorAll('.player__slider');
const butto = player.querySelector('.buttom')

//toggle 

function togglePlay(){
    if(video.paused){
        video.play();
        if (butto.style.display === "none") {
           butto.style.display === "block";
          }
         else{butto.style.display = "none"} 
    }else{
        video.pause();
        if (butto.style.display === "block") {
            butto.style.display === "none";
          }else{butto.style.display ="block"}
    }
}
function updateButton(){
    const icon = this.paused ? '▷':'❚❚';
    toggle.textContent = icon;
    const videoclic = this.paused? '▷':'❚❚';
    butto.textContent= videoclic
}
video.addEventListener('click',togglePlay);
video.addEventListener('play',updateButton);
video.addEventListener('pause',updateButton);

toggle.addEventListener('click',togglePlay);
butto.addEventListener('click',togglePlay);
butto.addEventListener('play',updateButton);
butto.addEventListener('pause',updateButton);
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    background: #7A419B;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #7c1599 0%,#921099 48%,#7e4ae8 100%);
    background-size: cover;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .player {
    max-width: 750px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  /* This css is only applied when fullscreen is active. */
  .player:fullscreen {
    max-width: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .player:-webkit-full-screen {
    max-width: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .player__video {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .player__button {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 50px;
  }
  
  .player__button:focus {
    border-color: #ffc600;
  }
  
  .player__slider {
    width: 10px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .player__controls {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(100%) translateY(-5px);
    transition: all .3s;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }
  
  .player:hover .player__controls {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .player:hover .progress {
    height: 15px;
  }
  
  .player__controls > * {
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .progress {
    flex: 10;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    cursor: ew-resize;
  }
  
  .progress__filled {
    width: 50%;
    background: #ffc600;
    flex: 0;
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
  
  /* unholy css to style input type="range" */
  
  input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 5px;
  }
  
  input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8.4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    border-radius: 1.3px;
    border: 0.2px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  }
  
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #ffc600;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -3.5px;
    box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
  
  input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #bada55;
  }
  
  input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8.4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 1.3px;
    border: 0.2px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  }
  
  input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #ffc600;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .buttom{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left:50%;
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.75);
      border-radius: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      cursor:pointer;
      animation-name: sizes ;
      animation-duration: 500ms;
      transform-origin: top left;      
      font-size: 35px;
      position: absolute;
      color: white;
      top: 50%;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
  }

  @keyframes sizes{
    0%   {transform: scale(1)
         translate(-50%, -50%);}
    100% {transform: scale(0)
        translate(-50%, -50%);}
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HTML Video Player</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

   <div class="player">
     <video class="player__video viewer" src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2019-05/small_watermarked/190416_08_Whales_Drone_004_preview.webm"  allowfullscreen></video>
            <button class ='buttom'>▷</button>
        <div class="player__controls">
            <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress__filled"></div>
       </div>
       <button class="player__button toggle" title="Toggle Play">►</button>
       <input type="range" name="volume" class="player__slider" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1">
       <input type="range" name="playbackRate" class="player__slider" min="0.5" max="2" step="0.1" value="1">
       <button data-skip="-10" class="player__button">« 10s</button>
       <button data-skip="25" class="player__button">25s »</button>
     </div>
   </div>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the comparison operator of "===" when you meant to use the assignment operator of "=" here in your JavaScript: butto.style.display === "block";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked through the Code, and if i understood the question correct you could add eventlisteners to the play and pause functions. This is how i solved the problem in your javascript file:

```
function togglePlay(){
if(video.paused){
    video.play();
    if (butto.style.display === "none") {
       butto.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        player.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverIcon);
        player.addEventListener('mouseout', hoverIconLeave);
     } } else {
    video.pause();
    if (butto.style.display === "block") {
        butto.style.display = "none";
      }else{butto.style.display = "block"}
    }
}
```

The functions i declared as separate functions outside of the "main" function for this, These are the functions:

```
function hoverIcon() {
    butto.style.display = "block";
}
function hoverIconLeave() {
    butto.style.display = "none"; 
}
```

The animation looks a bit off but that you can change in the CSS, hope this helped :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Joakim Engqvist I tried to solve the problem on my own and I solved it, but your result looks better and simpler.

Comment: Great to hear :)